# Convert Excel to PDF in SSIS Not Working

Tags: vb.net, excel, pdf, ssis

I have SSIS code that converts Excel to PDF in a script task similar to this posts code: [Code to Convert Excel to PDF using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805450/code-to-convert-excel-to-pdf-using-vb-net). The SSIS job runs all the way to where it exports to excel:

```
oWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(pFormatType, PDFFileName, pQuality, _
pIncludeDocProperties, _
pIgnorePrintAreas, _
pFrom, pTo, pOpenAfterPublish)
```

Once it hits this block of code my SSIS job freezes. I have my application.displayalerts set to false thinking that somethiing pops up but that is not the problem. I also have PDF reader installed on my server and that doesn't help either. This code works on my PC but not on the server. I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening. It seems like the code referenced in the link does work also. Any ideas why my code doesn't work on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I dug a bit deeper. I was able to run SQL Agent in interactive mode and I could see a pop up stuck in Excel (or at least see a pop up with a title "printer setup", the screen was all wigged out otherwise). I googled that and found this other posting: [Excel automation: PDF export causes "Printer setup" popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936748/excel-automation-pdf-export-causes-printer-setup-popup) that describes my problem. He fixed his problem, which worked for me as well, by changing the default printer to the microsoft XPS document printer. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably call desktop applications from a server process that has no desktop.

It's probably missing something like Acrobat or a print queue and is waiting for user input that will never come.

If you need to reliably create PDFs from excel using an automated process, you'll need to look at 3rd party tools or writing something.

I can't locate it right now, but Microsoft has a technote somewhere that mentions this.

Comment: I assume I can use SSRS to create the report and then output from there although I am hoping to not have to do that and that there may be a way to force or ignore the user input piece that is possibly happening. Reason is because I would have to write a ton of SSRS reports for the number of files that gets converted to PDF from Excel.

Comment: SSRs can output PDFs via the .net api SOAP based

Comment: If i recall, but you'll need to write it to a file yourself. You can also do them manually from a web browser or schedule them.